# Is there a way to tap on a marker and return that image into fullscreen?

Tags: android, google-maps

i have an app where the marker is an image taken by the camera and returned as a thumbnail.   Now the problem i have is that when implementing the `onMarkerClick` to display the full sized it then only returns the latest image taken for when tapping on all the markers.

So is there a way to save the marker's ID or image to that marker so when the user taps on that marker to display the full image that image for that marker will show?

here is my onMarkerClick code i have so far:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker arg0){
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + destinationFile);
  intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
  startActivity(intent);
  return false;
```

With this code, it displays the last image taken by the camera.

Could someone please help and also maybe provide some code that will help me with this problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

`onMapLongClick`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

`onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{ 
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        File imageStorageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"My Folder");
        if (!imageStorageFolder.exists())
        {
            imageStorageFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG , "Folder created at: "+imageStorageFolder.toString());
        }
       if (data != null)
        {
            String filename = "image";
            String fileNameExtension = ".jpg";
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String imageStorageFolder1 = File.separator+"My Folder"+File.separator;
            markerImagePathMap.put(markerId, imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension);
            Log.d(TAG, "the destination for image file is: " + markerImagePathMap );
            if (data.getExtras() != null)
            {
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream((File) markerImagePathMap);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR:" + e.toString());
                }
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .draggable(true)
                            .snippet("snippet")
                            .title("Title")
                            .position(point)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromBitmap(bitmap));
                            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

`onMarkerClick`

```
@Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker){
        markerId = marker.getId();

        if(markerImagePathMap.get(marker.getId() == null) != null){
            // take image for marker
        }
        else{
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + markerImagePathMap.get(markerId));
            intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
```

The Problem is though that there are errors under `marker.getId();` saying `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int`  as well as under `if(markerImagePathMap.**get**(marker.getId() == null)){`  saying `The method get(int) in the type SparseArray<String> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)`

Comment: It seems is dependent on the `destinationFile` String. Seems you might want to look into creating a map that maps from a marker to a file String. Then when you click on a marker, get the string that marker maps to.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i was thinking in the same line as that but can't find an example to help?  would you maybe know how do it?

Comment: So you have the image file paths when the activity starts? Or you click  a marker and take an image to set an image to that marker? How are you setting the images to each individual marker?

Comment: Well i tap on the point on the map and then take and image (Camera Intent) and return a thumbnail to that point,  now i just need to tap the thumbnail and return the full image.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to put this as a comment, but it got sloppy. Without knowing exactly how you are handling your project some of this code may be off, but the idea is still there.

1. Create the following class variable

   ```
   private Map<String, String> markerImagePathMap;
   ```
2. Create a HashMap to map your marker id's to their destination file

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate...{
       super.onCreate...;

       markerImagePathMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
   }
   ```
3. Modify your onActivityResult() method to store your marker and it's associated file path

   ```
   String destinationFilePath = imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension;
   Marker marker = googleMaps.addMarker(markerOptions);
   markerImagePathMap.put(marker.getId(), destinationFilePath);
   ```
4. In onMarkerCLick(Marker marker) update the method to something like

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + markerImagePathMap.get(marker.getId());
   intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
   startActivity(intent);
   return false;
   ```

**EDIT NOTES**

1. changed markerImagePathMap from a SparseArray to a HashMap
2. use dynamically created marker's id as the key for the Map.

**UPDATE**

I feel like your issue is coming in onActivityResult(). It would look like

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ 
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        File imageStorageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"My Folder");
        if (!imageStorageFolder.exists()){
            imageStorageFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG , "Folder created at: "+imageStorageFolder.toString());
        }
        if (data != null){
            String filename = "image";
            String fileNameExtension = ".jpg";
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String imageStorageFolder1 = File.separator+"My Folder"+File.separator;

            /** CHANGE **/
            String destinationFilePath = imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension;
            Log.d(TAG, "the destination for image file is: " + destinationFilePath );
            /** DONE CHANGE **/

            if (data.getExtras() != null){
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                try{
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream((File) markerImagePathMap);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "ERROR:" + e.toString());
            }

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .draggable(true)
                .snippet("snippet")
                .title("Title")
                .position(point)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromBitmap(bitmap));

            /** CHANGE **/
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            markerImagePathMap.put(marker.getId(), destinationFilePath);
            /** DONE CHANGE **/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,  Have implemented your suggestion, but it gives some errors.  I have updated my question with the code.  Please see above.

Comment: @Allrounder please take a look at my updated answer. You need to reincorporate your destinationFile String, but just locally so that you can later use it as the value for your map.

Comment: Great no errors now, but when tapping on the marker now it brings up an icon of an image that is broken?  so it doesn't seem to find the path.  I will updated my onactivityresult code and onmarkerclick code.

Comment: Okay so sorry to bother you, but have done what you said but getting this error now, `The method put(String, String) in the type Map<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, File)`  under `markerImagePathMap.put(marker.getId(), destinationFile);`  Would it be possible for you to update my question with your code?  Again sorry for bothering you, have been at this the whole day and not finding a solution.

Comment: @Allrounder Read over my addition of `destinationFilePath` in onActivityResult. You can add that line in place of `markerImagePathMap.put(markerId, imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension);` in your code. Make sure you read through my edited post as my answer seems to be different from your questions code.

Comment: Thanks,  The app crashes now, saying `Nullpointer file = null`.  But don't worry too much,  I think i am going to call it a day and look at it with fresh eyes in the morning.  I think however though its not saving the file therefore when tapping onmapclick it crashed with `12-10 21:39:00.385: E/(20359): ERROR:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.io.File`

Comment: @Allrounder the issue is that, somewhere, I am mistyping a variable that you are trying to use. Right now, somewhere, you are trying to cast a HashMap to a File, but that shouldn't happen. You might have put my changes into your code wrong somewhere, you shouldn't be attempting to use a file with your HashMap anywhere. All your HashMap contains is a String key (your marker id) that maps to the file path (not the file itself).

Comment: Well in a nutshell,  tap map - take picture - return thumbnail - place on map <-- this works.  Tap on marker and the app crashes.  So in my mind i need to save that image to that marker to recall when the marker has been tapped.  It shouldn't be that difficult :-) Anyway, thanks so much for your help really appreciate it!  will work on this again in the morning.  Please (if you don't mind) could you still assist me with this?